# Add onclick event to material table react js

Tags: reactjs, onclick, material-table

I need to retrieve data from the server then I display this data in a table and if a user clicks on a button in the table he can download the file

Here is my data :

```
files = [ {name : "file1", created_at: "29/01/2021"},
          {name : "file2", created_at: "20/03/2021"}]
```

table headers :

```
const tableColumns = [
  { title: "name", field: "name" },

  {
    title: "Date",
    field: "created_at",
    type: "date",
    dateSetting: { locale: "en-GB" },
    filterComponent: (props) => <CustomDatePicker {...props} />
  }
];
```

My array :

```
{file && (
<Fragment>
<MaterialTable
columns={tableColumns}
data={file}
title="Material Table - Custom Filter Component"
options={{search: false, filtering: true }}

actions={[
  {
    icon: 'save',
    tooltip: 'Save User',
    onClick: () => window.open('http://localhost:5000/files/' + file.name, '_blank').focus()
  }
]}
/>
</Fragment>)}
```

I get the error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/Users/admin//files/undefined'"}

how can i use in react js the link of each file, i tried to use the map function on my data but it doesn't work

Comment: Hey @Cissus I just answered this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69037532/10569220).

Answer (score 0):

Even it works on your computer, the code won't work in a public server. because no one knows what is `http://localhost:5000`.

In order to get that line working, you need to find a resources that can be reached in your browser, ex. `google.com`

And then give it a shot and see if you still run into that error.

NOTE: client app such as a website can't work with a physical file in your computer. That is not allowed, but once you publish to the web, it becomes another URL which could store a file.

Comment: @windmaomo that's not the problem, I have an api that allows to get the file from the server, but the question is rather how to add a link in an object

Comment: what do you mean by add a link in an object, did you describe this issue in your question description?

Comment: yes I would like to add a link to an object

Comment: like this files = [ {name : "file1", created_at: "29/01/2021", link : "http://localhost:5000/files/' + file.name"}],