# add link to object array

Tags: reactjs, object, material-table

I need to get data from the server then I display this data in a table (react js) and if a user clicks on a button in the table he can download the file

```
 <Table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>File Name</th>
          <th>Date</th>
          <th>Download file</th>

        </tr>
      </thead>
      {files &&  (
      <tbody className="text-content-dark">
      {files.map(file => (
        <tr>
        <td>{file.name}</td>
        <td>{file.date}</td>

        <td>
        <Button
            className="btn-large btn-primary fit-content"
            icon="arrowRight"
            iconPosition="right"
            onClick={() => window.open('http://localhost:5000/files/' + file.name, '_blank').focus()}>
            Download
          </Button>
         </td>
      </tr>
    ))}
      </tbody>
       )}
    </Table>
```

now i want to use material-table but i didn't find a way to add the link to each object
example of data :

```
files = [ {name : "file1", created_at: "29/01/2021", link : "localhost:5000/files" + "file1"},
          {name : "file2", created_at: "20/03/2021",link : "localhost:5000/files" + "file2"}]
```

material-table :

```
{files && (
<Fragment>
<MaterialTable
columns={tableColumns}
data={files}
title="Material Table - Custom Filter Component"
options={{ search: false, filtering: true }}

actions={[
  {
    icon: 'save',
    tooltip: 'Save User',
    onClick: () => window.open('http://localhost:5000/files/' + files.name, '_blank').focus()
  }
]}


/>

</Fragment>)}
```

but i get error file undifined ;

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you are missing is the access to the data from each row within the custom action you are defining.
Consider this example where the action is defined as a function where `rowData` is a parameter which contains every field of the clicked row:

```
 actions={[
          (rowData) => {
            return {
              icon: "save",
              tooltip: "Get file!",
              onClick: (event, rowData) => {
                alert("Save file of " + rowData.name);
              }              
            };
          }
        ]}
```

[image: example_from_sandbox]

Here is the link to the [working sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-table-custom-action-j623x?file=/src/App.js). Let me know if that worked for you!